# Rails: Update score of an user after he wrote a comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

i'm really new to Rails and i'm wondering, how the following could be done:

After an user has written a comment for a sin ( =article), the author ( =user) should get 20 points (for example) added to his score (= user.score). score is a column in my Users table.

My models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :absolutions, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sin
end

class Sin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

My comments controller looks like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @sin = Sin.find(params[:sin_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.sin_id = @sin.id
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
      redirect_to sin_path(@sin)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment was not created."
      redirect_to sin_path(@sin)
    end
  end

end
```

After spending several hours to get this on my own, i'm a little confused. After creating a comment, i would like change a specific value of the **associated object** User.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add it after save :

```
if @comment.save
  flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
  current_user.score += 20
  current_user.save
  redirect_to sin_path(@sin)
else
```

BUT, it's always better to do it in your model. So i would create an add_score instance method in your user model and update the score there. Then, i would just call that method in the controller, in the same spot.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your advice and inserted it at first into the controller, but I get the following error: undefined method `score' for #<User:0x007ff48818cc50>.

Comment: This means that you do not have a score attribute in your user model. Add it please :)

Comment: Oh, my fault, I renamed that column before putting the code here. Now, the comment is created (with your suggested code in comments controller), BUT the value of user.score isn't updated.

Comment: it's not updated because you either have attr_accessible, or the validations fail. You can use update_attribute to save the value.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. NOW, it works. I'm using the following lines (coins = score): 

coins_new = current_user.coins + 20
current_user.update_attribute(:coins, coins_new)

Many thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Define an `after_save` callback in your comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]

  after_save :add_score

  private

  def add_score
    self.user.score += 20
    self.user.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, when I insert these lines, I get an error: undefined method `score' for "#<User:0x000000039f9ae0>":User.

Comment: This was assuming you have a score attribute in your `User` model meaning a column in your `user` table in the database.  If you don't have that then you will have to add it through a migration and then it will work.

Comment: One more thing that I was going to add here: The `after_save` method will run every time the comment is saved to the database, even when you update it. I am assuming that you only want to increase the user's score when he/she creates a new comment, not necessarily when updates it. Having said that you probably want to have an `after_create` callback instead of `after_save`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an after_create callback in your comment model that makes the change in the corresponding user?

This kind of logic doesn't belong in the controller.